# MagicalRecord not using CocoaLumberJack

Tags: magicalrecord, cocoalumberjack

I want to add verbose logging to MagicalRecord to try and capture any errors that are happening as I’ve had a couple of users report data loss.

I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Logging

CocoaLumberJack is included in the `.pch` and, for good measure, at the top of App Delegate includes.

```
@import CocoaLumberjack;
static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelAll;
```

MagicalRecord is included as the last include in App Delegate.

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h> // import last so it is included after CocoaLumberjack
```

The App Delegate instantiates CocoaLumberJack and then later MagicalRecord.

I have set the logging level in MR to verbose:

```
[MagicalRecord setLoggingLevel:MagicalRecordLoggingLevelVerbose];
```

I can see the MR logging coming out in the console, but it is not getting sent to CocoaLumberJack which is set to also write the logs to file.

I am using CocoaPods, the highlights of my `podfile` are

```
platform :ios , '10.0'
swift_version = "4.0"

use_frameworks!

pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'MagicalRecord/CocoaLumberjack'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
```

What am I missing?